# ¿Cómo puedo evitar la inserción SQL a la BD cuando recargo la página?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando una cesta y cuando guardo su nombre, paso a la página en la que realizo la inserción con mysql_query() y me enseña el contenido en una tabla. El problema está en que cuando refresco la página, la inserción se realiza de nuevo. He probado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

$producto es la descripción y $x es la cantidad que queremos de un mismo producto. ¿Cómo he de tratar $sqlLinea y $resposeLinea respecto al condicional? Almacenándolos fuera no evita la inserción sql al hacer refresh en la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una técnica simple que puedes usar es separar la inserción de la página que muestra los resultados.

Es decir:

1. Muestras el formulario (Con action => insertar.php)
2. Dentro de insertar.php

   1. Tomas los datos del formulario
   2. Realizas la inserción
   3. Redireccionas a otro archivo donde se muestran los resultados.